# How can I transfer an image from table cell to newviewcontroller using prepare for segue?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, segue

How can I transfer an image from table cell to the Newviewcontroller using prepare for segue? I was able to transfer the label data but not the image. I am using parse.com as my backend to retrieve the image. thanks

```
import UIKit

 class mainVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,  {

@IBOutlet weak var resultsTable: UITableView!

var resultsStartdateArray = [String]()
var resultsTweetImageFiles = [PFFile?]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return resultsTweetImageFiles.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 350
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:mainCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! mainCell
    cell.dateLbl.text = self.resultsStartdateArray[indexPath.row]
  resultsTweetImageFiles[indexPath.row]?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                cell.tweetImg.image = image


            }

        })
    return cell
}

 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

let upcoming: NewViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! NewViewController


let indexPath = self.resultsTable.indexPathForSelectedRow!

let titleString = self.resultsStartdateArray[indexPath.row] as String
let imageTitle = self.resultsTweetImageFiles[indexPath.row] as PFFile?// i have tried this but it didnt work 

upcoming.imageTitle == imageTitle // << not working 
upcoming.titleString = titleString

self.resultsTable.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}


import UIKit

class NewViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var dateLbl: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var tweetImage: UIImageView!

var titleString: String!

var imageTitle: UIImage!

override func viewDidLoad()
{

    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.dateLbl.text = self.titleString

    self.tweetImage.image = self.imageTitle

}
```

Comment: In principle you are on the right track. So what is your real problem? What is the contents of `self.resultsTweetImageFiles`? Did you check that? Is it helpful to know that `sender` refers to your cell view (or to the subview of it with which the segue was connected in the storyboard editor)?

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code you create `imageTitle` as `PFFile` object:

```
let imageTitle = self.resultsTweetImageFiles[indexPath.row] as PFFile?
```

And then you try set it to `UIImage` reference:

```
upcoming.imageTitle == imageTitle
```

But `imageTitle` from `NewViewController` expects the image with `UIImage` type and not some incomprehensible for it object like `PFFile`

That's why it does not work.

To fix it you need to convert data from your `PFFile` object to `UIImage` and only then transmit it to your `NewViewController` object. You did not write the form in which the data contained in your `PFFile` object so assume that it `NSData` format for example. In this case you can do something like this:

```
if let imageObject = self.resultsTweetImageFiles[indexPath.row] as? PFFile {
    if let imageData = imageObject.getData as? NSData {
        if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
            upcoming.imageTitle = image
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you have the some `String` object that contain your image in `base64` format you can first convert it to `NSData` object like this:

```
let imageData = NSData(base64EncodedString: imageString, options: .IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
```